# What does C understand when a function header is not followed by a compound-statement?

Tags: c

I'd like to understand the nature of the errors "expected declaration specifiers before 'for' " and "...before 'i' "

What does the compiler actually understand from this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
int i, j, m[5][5];
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    *(*m + i) = i;
i = 0, j = 0;
```

It doesn't matter what the code does (or would do, if I included it in braces). I'd like to know what does C expect after the function header if it is not followed by a compound-statement or a semicolon (to mark a prototype).

Thank you in advance

Comment: It notices a syntax error. It expects curly braces

Comment: Interestingly, it may not notice until the semicolon after `m[5][5]` because up to then, it looks like an old-style function declaration.  (Of course, `i`, `j` and `m[5][5]` are not in the argument list, and `void` is, so a smarter compiler will find many things to complain about before it notices the missing open-curly.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parsers check syntax first.
The syntax for function definitions is ([6.9.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1))

> function-definition:
>
> ```
>    declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-listopt compound-statement
> ```

In your case `declaration-specifiers` is `int`, `declarator` is `main(void)` and now
you're in `declaration-list_opt`, which is there to support K&R definitions such as `int main(argc, argv) int argc; char **argv { }`.

A commented K&R function definition:

```
/*the old declarator mirrors usage
  -- it takes an identifier list rather than a param-declarator list
  (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6)
*/

int main(argc, argv)

/*the types of the identifiers are then declared*/

int argc;
char **argv;

/*and only then comes the function body
  which is technically a compound statement
*/
{
}
```

In your case, `declaration-list_opt` is matched with:

```
int i, j, m[5][5];
```

which semantically doesn't make sense with `main(void)` (the array declaration wouldn't make sense with any function declarator, really, since arrays are passed as pointers), but checking that would be part of a semantic check, which usually comes *after* syntax verification.

After `declaration-list_opt`, a `compound-statement` (i.e., `{}`-braced function body) is syntactically expected.`for` fails that syntactic expectation.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Really makes sense what "for" stands for in the parser's eyes.

Comment: @Deathcofi A token that's illegal in the context you put it in. `for` can only begin a `for`-loop. `for` is definitely neither a possible beginning of a declaration nor a possible beginning of a compound statement (only a left curly can be that) so it's a syntax fail.